# ClassNotFoundException for AvroSchema while saving to hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, submit

I am trying to get data from hive, and saving it to hdfs,
I am getting classnotfound exception for avro schema while saving to hdfs using 
`saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset`, I am executing using spark-submit
Please have a look at the code,

```
withValues.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    outputPath,
    classOf[IdentifiersData],
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable],
    classOf[AvroKeyOutputFormat[IdentifiersData]],
    conf.getConfiguration)
```

Any help??
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to package your driver app into a single JAR containing all dependencies when sending it with `spark-submit`

Comment: @Sebastian , not necessary, if the jars are present on the class path of all executors or within spark lib, it will be picked automatically when using spark-submit.   In this particular scenario, i think user is trying to directly run the job using java -jar, or sbt run

Comment: Will you be able to post the stack trace.?